# mu4e reply from the correct account

Tags: email, emacs, mu4e

I have several accounts associated with mu4e and I can both receive and send - using smtpmail-multi - from all them without problems. I am not using contexts. The relevant parts in my configuration look like this:

```
(setq message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line)
(setq message-citation-line-format "On %a, %b %d %Y, %f wrote:\n")
(setq smtpmail-multi-accounts
      (quote
       ((yahoo . ("xxxx@yahoo.com"
                 "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
                 587
                 "xxxxx@yahoo.com"
                 nil nil nil nil))
    (other . ("xxxxx@other.com"
                 "smtp.other.com"
                 465
         "xxxx@other.com"
                 ssl nil nil nil))
    (etc . ("xx@etc.com"
                 "smtp.etc.com"
                 465
         "xx@etc.com"
                 ssl nil nil nil))
     ;; ... 
    )))

(setq smtpmail-multi-associations
      (quote
       (("xxxx@yahoo.com" yahoo)
    ("xxx@other.com" other)
    ("xx@etc.com" etc)
     ;; ....
    )))

(setq smtpmail-multi-default-account (quote yahoo))
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-multi-send-it)

(setq mu4e-compose-dont-reply-to-self t)
(setq mu4e-user-mail-address-list '("xxxx@yahoo.com"
                    "xxx@other.com"
                    "xx@etc.com"
                     ;; ...
                     ))

(setq user-full-name "XXXXXX")
(setq user-mail-address "xxx@other.com")
```

This way I can properly send emails from the right account just by typing the address of my email in the `FROM:` field.

When replying, I want mu4e to identify the account to which the message has been send and update `FROM:` field accordingly so that I don't have to type in the proper account all the time myself. I am looking for a way to do this without having to upgrade my entire configuration to using contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of tweaking I came up with this:

```
(defun my-mu4e-set-account ()
  "Set the account for composing a message."
  (if mu4e-compose-parent-message
      (let ((mail (cdr (car (mu4e-message-field mu4e-compose-parent-message :to)))))
    (if (member mail mu4e-user-mail-address-list)
        (setq user-mail-address mail)
      (setq user-mail-address "my@default.account")))
    (helm :sources
      `((name . "Select account: ")
        (candidates . mu4e-user-mail-address-list)
        (action . (lambda (candidate) (setq user-mail-address candidate)))))))

(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-pre-hook 'my-mu4e-set-account)
```

where `mu4e-user-mail-address-list` is, obviously, a list with my mail accounts

This will reply with the proper account and, more, will open a helm mini menu asking me which account to use every time I compose a new message.

Comment: Wish I could more than +1 this. Thanks for the snippet!

Comment: If you use Ivy instead of Helm, you can replace `(helm :sources ...)` with `(ivy-read "Account: " mu4e-user-mail-address-list)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this [blog post](http://cachestocaches.com/2017/3/complete-guide-email-emacs-using-mu-and-/) has a multi account setup that automatically picks up the FROM field. Might want to take a look at it. Mu4e is on my todo list so I can't give you a direct answer.